# How to prove the existence of groups for bipartite graph?

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

I have a simple bipartite graph with bipartition (W, C) such that $|W| < |C|$, each vertex $c \in C$ has 2 edges (so to two different vertices w each time) and each vertex $w \in W$ has 4 edges. I would like to prove the existence of groups that are made of 2 vertices $w$ each time, where both vertices have an edge to the same vertex $c$. Here is an example of such [Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLUzg.jpg).

This problem is just an example with values of a bigger problem where I need to look for the existence of groups that give me the smallest possible number of groups, and I have different values instead of 2 and 4 for the number of edges of vertices in C or W. So if you have any idea/hint/it makes you think of some problem: it is highly welcomed!

Comment: From what I understand of your question, this is set-cover: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem